# How do I Reset My Chrome Extension on Re-enabling?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome extension that, when you click the icon, background.js, executes the content script and changes from the "off" icon to the "on" icon.

The problem is, when I disable the extension, and then re-enable, the content script isn't loaded, but the icon is still showing as "on" when I want it to default to "off" so the user knows they need to re-click to activate.

Here is my background.js script:

```
var turnedOff = true;
var loadScript = true;

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"red.png"});
});

  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if (loadScript == true) {
          loadScript = false;
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"green.png"});
          chrome.tabs.query( {} ,function (tabs) { 
          for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: "content.js"});
          }
        });
      }
     else if (turnedOff == true) {
        turnedOff = false;
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"green.png"});
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "On"}, function(response) {});
        });
     }
     else if (turnedOff == false) {
        turnedOff = true;
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"red.png"});
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "Off"}, function(response) {});
        });
     }
  });
```

And here is my manifest.json:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js", "jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ],
      "persistent": false
   },
   "browser_action": {
       "name" : "hjfdsfhdks"
   },
   "icons" : {
       "16" : "red.png",
       "48" : "red.png",
       "128" : "red.png"
   },
   "description": "Replace Facebook color-background posts with Kanye West quotes to match the bold, brazen, attention-grabbing aesthetic.",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Ye'sbook",
   "permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.2",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "images/*.png" ]
}
```

Pardon if it doesn't look very clean, I am just trying to get it to work before refactoring and am new to Chrome extensions.

Worth noting: background.js reloads properly when closing down Chrome entirely, but not on re-enabling. Also, the reason I have my content script loading in background as opposed to having manifest.json handle is, I want this event to take place immediately upon clicking as opposed to only having the content script load on the page refresh.

Comment: You can "ping" the active page at the start of your event script by sending a message. The content script would respond to this "ping" message with e.g. `true`. After re-enabling the message won't be received and the response will be `undefined` which is the telltale of the extension being re-enabled. Then you can update the icon and re-inject your content script(s) into the open page.

Comment: In chrome docs, do you mean activeTab? I appreciate the response but since I am new to Chrome Extension development, don't quite understand what you're referring to. If it's activeTab, my code currently is set to run content scripts on all open tabs in the event that a user clicks on the icon while not on Facebook, which is the tab I need the script to run on. Again, there are some serious code smells with that and I'm sure there's an easier way to verify url and only run script on match, but I'm new to chrome development and just want it to work first.

Comment: Still need help with this. Anyone?

Comment: I guess it's not easy to help without trying out your extension and writing code for you, which is cumbersome. Anyway, I don't see what's stopping you from sending the ping message to all tabs. Also, you may want to write something much much more simple first to make sure you understand the extension architecture, which is actually quite simple.

Comment: Because pinging tabs is a very general comment that I can't get any results for when I search for docs. Also, I have been starting with much smaller experiments and then adding to my extension. If you have a link to "pinging tabs" or if there's an alternate way of phrasing that, that would be super helpful but I do have a healthy understanding of the architecture of chrome extensions, after spending a lot of time with this one.

Comment: Still looking for help on this please. Any docs or specific references would be super helpful.